# On click play youtube videos in fullscreen on phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I have several embeded youtube videos on my page using iframe tag. Is it possible that when any user clicks on a video on a handheld device the video goes fullscreen?

Comment: Did you explored the Youtube's API reference ? https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=pt-br#Getting_Started

Comment: Yes. But couldn't understand it properly.